# Itô correction on the Schrödinger equation

Tags: schroedinger-equation, stochastic-processes

$\textbf{Introduction:} $

Given a time-dependent Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}(t)$, and a state $|\psi(t)\rangle$, one would like to solve the Schrödinger equation
\begin{equation}
  i\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle=H(t)|\psi(t)\rangle
\end{equation}

First, we go to an eigenbasis of the Hamiltonian, $\mathcal{H}(t)|\phi_n(t)\rangle=E_n(t)|\phi_n(t)\rangle$ and express the original state in this new basis, $|\psi(t)\rangle=\sum_nc_n(t)|\phi_n(t)\rangle$.

We can plug the state in this new basis into the Schrödinger equation such as
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_n c_n(t)|\phi(t)_n\rangle=\dot{c}_n(t)|\phi_n(t)\rangle+c_n(t)|\dot{\phi}_n(t)\rangle
\end{equation}

and find an equation of motion for the coefficients $c_n(t)$:
\begin{equation}
\dot{c}_m(t) + \sum_n c_n(t) \langle\phi_m(t)|\dot{\phi}_n(t)\rangle=-iE_m(t) c_m(t)
\end{equation}
For more details, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem.

$\textbf{Question:}$

My question is what happens if $\mathcal{H}(t)=\mathcal{H}_{0}+\alpha(t)\mathcal{H}_{s}$, where $\alpha(t)$ is a stochastic variable following $\overline{\alpha(t)}=0$ and $\overline{\alpha(t)\alpha(t')}=\delta(t-t')$.  I would like to work with the Itô representation, because it simplifies later expectation values, such as $\overline{c_n \alpha(t)}=0$.

Do I need to consider the term $\dot{c}_n(t)|\dot{\phi}_n(t)\rangle$ (Itô correction)? The Hamiltonian is linear with respect to the stochastic variable, but the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are not.

If so, I would get an equation of motion for the stochastic coefficients as

\begin{equation}
\dot{c}_m(t) + \sum_n c_n(t) \langle\phi_m(t)|\dot{\phi}_n(t)\rangle+ \sum_n \dot{c}_n(t) \langle\phi_m(t)|\dot{\phi}_n(t)\rangle=-iE_m(t) c_m(t)
\end{equation}

Comment: It is difficult to understand if you need an "Itô correction" because it is not clear what the meaning of the coefficients $c_n$ and eigenvalues $E_m$ are. Can you state their relation to the process $\alpha$? Within the Itô calculus, you include extra terms when you use changes of variables and the chain rule. I recommend reading Van Kampen's paper https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01007642.pdf